# Excel VBA - Website Scrape

Tags: html, excel, web-scraping, vba

I have spent hours searching for the answer to this, but I can't find one.

I am trying to extract data from this [website](http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/leicester-manchester-united/G0fXjMCK/)

I have managed to get most of what I need, but I'm finding it difficult to target a specific data point.

The closest piece of code I've used is:

```
 hDoc.getElementsByClassName("table-matches__odds")(0).outerHTML
```

which outputs the below which isn't what I want

> class=table-matches__odds data-odd-max="5.50" data-odd="5.19"

I only want the `data-odd=` part of this, so the 5.19 but can't figure out how to target it. I could use instr to pull the data I need out of that, but is there a more specific way?

The html looks like this for the section i'm trying to extract:

```html
<TH class=h-text-left colSpan=8><A href="about:/soccer/england/premier-league/">Premier League 2016/2017</A></TH></TR>
<TR data-dt="5,2,2017,17,00">
<TD>Leicester</TD>
<TD><STRONG>Manchester United</STRONG></TD>
<TD class=h-text-center>0:3</TD>
<TD class=table-matches__odds data-odd-max="5.50" data-odd="5.19"></TD>
<TD class=table-matches__odds data-odd-max="4.00" data-odd="3.79"></TD>
<TD class="table-matches__odds colored"><SPAN><SPAN><SPAN data-odd-max="1.80" data-odd="1.72"></SPAN></SPAN></SPAN></TD>
<TD><A href="about:/soccer/england/premier-league/leicester-manchester-united/G0fXjMCK/">details</A></TD>
<TD class=h-text-right>05.02.2017</TD></TR>
<TR data-dt="24,9,2016,13,30">
<TD><STRONG>Manchester United</STRONG></TD>
<TD>Leicester</TD>
<TD class=h-text-center>4:1</TD>
<TD class="table-matches__odds colored"><SPAN><SPAN><SPAN data-odd-max="1.73" data-odd="1.69"></SPAN></SPAN></SPAN></TD>
<TD class=table-matches__odds data-odd-max="4.05" data-odd="3.85"></TD>
<TD class=table-matches__odds data-odd-max="5.75" data-odd="5.34"></TD>
<TD><A href="about:/soccer/england/premier-league/manchester-united-leicester/dOBfynxf/">details</A></TD>
<TD class=h-text-right>24.09.2016</TD></TR>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could declare it as a string

`Dim sResult as String`

and then derive the 5.19 value with this:

`sResult = Mid(sResult, InStr(sResult, "data-odd=""") + Len("data-odd="""), 4)`
 - this assumes that it's always 2 decimal places and it's also stored as a string rather then a double

Out of interest, are you trying to build an arbing screener?

Comment: Hi Jeremy - I was going to try that approach and it probably does the trick. Just wondered if there was a way of directly referencing it like you can with tags and classes etc. I'm building a football prediction model, and I'll use the odds to validate any profit gains. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @smdavies1983 I've tried building a scraper but my htlm isn't up to par at the moment to do it with differing page layouts etc.. have you tried the `innerHTML` property? I'm kinda guessing here, not knowing your code though

Comment: Yeah I tried a host of different things - innertext, innerhtml. Outerhtml gave me the output closest to what I needed. Other data on the page was fine because they had defined classes or tags. But data-odd doesn't seem to be defined in the standard way and might actually be jnjected into the code using javascrips